# Naming conversion functions

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

Which naming convention for conversions is standard across most languages?

```
convert_from_typea_to_typeb(arg)
```

or

```
convert_to_typeb_from_typea(arg)
```

Or is there another standard?

Comment: There is no standard. In C++, these are often operators which have neither name, and in Java, the issue rarely comes up. Your use of a $ suggests that you in fact have PHP in mind.

Comment: A much more interesting question is the choice between "int", "toInt", "stringToInt", and possibly "convertStringToInt". (...or "ToInt", or "to_int", ..., depending on the norm of the language.)

Comment: @bmar `$` just came from too much PHP usage.

Comment: Besides there being no single standard, this is inherently language-dependent. With strongly typed languages you don't neccessarily need to spell out the type of `from`, with dedicated `conversion` namespaces you might not need to prefix with `convert`, ...

Comment: @bmargulies: With C++ there are often code guidelines in place that require explicit conversion functions instead of operators due to the non-obviousness of implicit conversions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going for the OO approach here, (in the relevant namespace) have a `Convert` class with a bunch of overloads `To<TypeName>` like so:

```
public class Convert
{
    public Foo ToFoo(Bar instance);
    public Foo ToFoo(Baz instance);
    public Bar ToBar(Foo instance);
    public Bar ToBar(Baz instance);
    public Baz ToBaz(Foo instance);
    public Baz ToBaz(Bar instance);
}
```

**addition** since php came specifically into the conversation; you cannot really do "overloading" in php, but there is a way to do it:

    `class ConversionException extends Exception
    {
    }`

```
class Convert
{
    public static function ToFoo($instance)
    {
        $from_type = get_class($instance);
        $my_convert_method = $from_type . 'ToFoo';

        if (method_exists(__CLASS__, $my_convert_method))
        {
            return self::$my_convert_method($instance);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ConversionException(sprintf('Cannot convert %s to Foo.', $from_type));
        }
    }

    protected static function BarToFoo(Bar $instance)
    {
        /* conversion implementation here */
    }
    protected static function BazToFoo(Bar $instance)
    {
        /* conversion implementation here */
    }
    /* you get the point */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer, and purely subjective, would be the one that flows logically with source to destination.

```
ConvertStringToInt()
```

or

```
ConvertVisitorToCustomer()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in C(++) you would do it with cast operators, so none of these names would fit.

In Objective-C I've seen something like NSPointFromCGPoint(...), or you would give the old type simply in the constructor.

The only thing that I've seen *very* rarely are those functions with convert_x_to_y :-)

Comment: C doesn't have conversion operators and for C++ there are often code guidelines that prohibit them as it makes code hard to maintain when conversions are not spelled out explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no cross-language standard for this kind of thing. Most languages either provide a built-in way to do this (C/C++) or encourage you to find another way around it (Java/C#).

In most object-oriented languages you shouldn't need this sort of functionality. You should try to restructure your program so that you do not need to do any explicit conversions.

However, if you really need to do this, I'd say drop the "convert" at the beginning and do `<source>_to_<target>`. Examples: `string_to_int`, `int_to_float`, `foo_to_bar`, etc. (Of course, write these in whatever case your language prefers. For example, in C#: `StringToInt`; in JavaScript: `stringToInt`.)

Answer (score 0):

In general, `x_to_y` is more common.

However the `x_from_y` convention is better when chaining operation.

```
XXX = XXX_from_AAA @ AAA_from_BBB @ BBB_from_YYY @ YYY
```

vs

```
XXX = AAA_to_XXX @ BBB_to_AAA @ YYY_to_BBB @ YYY
```

For example:

```py
email = email_from_name[name_from_address[address_from_number['+336120324']]]
```

It is clear by grouping visually that there's no mistake in the code:

```py
(email = email)_from_(name[name)_from_(address[address)_from_(number['+336120324'])]]
```

By opposition, `XXX_to_YYY` require our brain to cross each variable, which is harder to parse and adds mental burden:

```py
email = name_to_email[address_to_name[number_to_adress['+336120324']]]
```

For a real case example, in geometry, people often have to chain transformations (project 3d point cloud from world coordinates to camera 3d coordinates to pixel 2d coordinates).

Some libraries like https://github.com/google-research/visu3d transformation API use the `x_from_y` convention for this reason:

```py
point3d = v3d.Point3d()  # Point cloud in world coordinates
cam_from_world = v3d.Transform()  # Projection world -> cam
px_from_cam = v3d.Transform()  # Projection cam -> px


# Project 3d world coordinated to camera 3d coordinates to pixel 2d
point2d = px_from_cam @ cam_from_world @ point3d
```

The `x_from_y` makes it clear that what is the reference frame of each variables:

```
point2d =  px_from_cam @ cam_from_world @ point3d
point2d =  px_from_(cam @ cam)_from_world @ point3d
point2d =  px_from_world @ point3d
```